# HOW CAN I GET RECORD ID FROM CKReference List in CloudKit

Tags: ios, swift, cloudkit

I have this 2 case:

1) Reference attribute on schema

```
let userReference = user!["friend"] as! CKReference
print(userReference.recordID)
```

2) Reference List attribute on schema

```
let userReferenceList = user!["friends"] as! [CKReference]
print(userReferenceList)
```

In the first one the console print the recordID and there is no problem. In the second the console print all the things but I can't put `userReferenceList.recordID`

If I code as`! CKReference` and not as `! [CKReference]` I can code `userReferenceList.recordID` method but app crashes.

NOW THE PROBLEM IS:

```
arraList
```

is always 1.

This 2 array are declared on the top of the class.

```
  var amicoList : [CKRecord] = [] 
  var arraList = []
```

the code is:

```
// ...

let user = records?.first
print(user!["surname"] as! String)


let userReferenceList = user!["friends"] as! [CKReference] // this is reference list on CloudKit schema

print(userReferenceList.count)
// here is ok, result is 2


for i in userReferenceList {
print(i.recordID)
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "recordID = %@", argumentArray: [i.recordID])
let query = CKQuery(recordType: "UserProfile", predicate: predicate)
publicData.performQuery(query, inZoneWithID: nil) {
(records, error) in
if error == nil {
for record in records! {
   print(record["name"]!)
   print(record["surname"]!)

   self.amicoList = records!
   self.arraList = self.amicoList
   print(self.arraList.count)
   // here is the problem, result is 1 instead of 2

   // ...
```

Comment: The 2nd is an array of references. Get a specific reference from the array then you can get the id from that reference.

Comment: Thankyou. Now I have another problem. See the code in this point print(self.arraList.count)